# How does the _ (underscore) work in the binding?

Tags: javascript

How does the _ (underscore) work in the binding?

```
function getDate(string) {
     let [_, month, day, year] = /(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{4})/.exec(string); 
return new Date(year, month -1, day); 
} 
                    
console.log(getDate("1-30-2003")); 
                
// → Thu Jan 30 2003 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

Comment: The same as anything else. `_` is a perfectly legal variable name (just like `$`), so you now literally have a variable called `_` in scope that has the value of whatever the right hand side `[0]` is. Slap a `console.log(_)` between your destructuring and return, and watch it log the entire pattern match. (on a more modern note, many IDE type checkers ignore variables starting with _, even though they shouldn't. It's a cheap way to mark something as "I don't care what's in this, I'm never doing anything with it". Except you absolutely can, it's just another perfectly normal variable)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is the underscore? Only 3 arguments are returned!

Answer (score 1):

`exec()` returns an array with the full matched string as the first item in the array, then each capturing group (parts surrounded by parenthesis) in the rest of the array items. so that first variable is just an unused but necessary garbage variable that contains the full date.

i wonder though if a better method might be:

```
let [month, day, year] = string.split( '-' );
```